# How to detect a small peak shoulder? using find_peaks and find_peaks_cwt

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use scipy find_peaks to detect the peaks seen in this spectrum here.
But I need to detect the shoulder peak (around x=3223 cm-1) as well, but I'm not successful. Any tips?

```
height = 0.02
indices, _ = find_peaks(y,height=height, threshold=None, distance=None, prominence=None, 
                        width=None, wlen=None, rel_height=None, plateau_size=None)
```

[image]

Comment: You could substract the peaks you already found by fitting a gauss or lorentz line shape to the profile and then analyze the residual spectrum again. However, it doesn't look like your shoulder peak is much different from background, so maybe increase measurement time also?

Comment: i can't re-measure this and need to use it as it is.